# Minimize code repetition in terms of python script arguments (with `argparse` or other modules)

Tags: python, python-3.x, argparse

Let's say one has several scripts: `script_1.py`, `script_2.py`, `script_3.py`, `script_4.py`, `script_5.py`, `script_6.py`, etc and the objective is to minimize code repetition in terms of arguments the scripts take as input.

As an example of scenarios:

- `script_1.py`, `script_2.py`, `script_3.py` have several arguments in common => possible solution: one can leverage parent_parser of argparse
- `script_4.py`, `script_5.py`, `script_6.py` have several arguments in common => possible solution: one can leverage parent_parser of argparse
- `script_5.py` `script_6.py`  `script_7.py` `script_8.py` have one argument in common => possible solution: put the args in a dictionary (snippet example below)

```py
"""
python run_app_w_argparse_example.py --arg_1 1
"""
import argparse
from typing import Dict

APPS_ARGS = {"--arg_1": dict(help="arg_1 description", type=int),
             "--arg_2": dict(help="arg_2 description", type=str, default="hi")}


def parser_example() -> Dict:
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description="Description")
    parser.add_argument("--arg_1", **APPS_ARGS["--arg_1"])
    return vars(parser.parse_args())


if __name__ == '__main__':
    print(parser_example())
```

One inconvenient is that "--arg1" gets repeated twice in add_argument. Is there a way to avoid that? Is there a better solution overall?

Comment: You could write a utility function that ends up calling `add_argument(key, **APPS_ARGS[key])`.

Answer (score 0):

This is a pattern that I occasionally use for python tools when using sub-commands or there are many scripts that share the same base args.

In short I create a nested structure (that I admit looks a bit horrible) that allows the parser to be dynamically created.

The basic layout is:

```py
args = Tuple[Tuple[str, ..., dict], ...]
```

Each inner `tuple` contains the CLI flags and a `dict` of the argument options.
the dict must be the final element.
The reason for doing it this way is because tuples can be appended to one another so arguments can be stacked up.

```py
import argparse

DEFAULT_SERVER_HOST = "127.0.0.1"
DEFAULT_SERVER_PORT = 5555
DEFAULT_TIMEOUT = 500

BASE_ARGS = (
    (
        "-H",  # FLAG
        "--host",  # FLAG
        dict(  # OPTIONS
            help="Server host address (default: {})".format(DEFAULT_SERVER_HOST),
            default=DEFAULT_SERVER_HOST,
        ),
    ),
    (
        "-P",
        "--port",
        dict(
            help="Server port (default: {})".format(DEFAULT_SERVER_PORT),
            default=DEFAULT_SERVER_PORT,
        ),
    ),
    (
        "-o",
        dict(type=str, help="Output filename", required=True),
    ),
    (
        "--timeout",
        dict(
            type=int,
            help="Connection timeout in seconds (default: {})".format(DEFAULT_TIMEOUT),
            default=DEFAULT_TIMEOUT,
        ),
    ),
)

def get_args(default_args=None, extra_args=None, prog=""):
    if default_args is None:
        args = BASE_ARGS
    else:
        args = default_args

    if extra_args is not None:
        args = args + extra_args

    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(prog)

    for *flags, opts in args:
        parser.add_argument(*flags, **opts)

    return parser, parser.parse_args()

def main():
    extra_args = (
        (
            "--log-file",
            dict(help="File to write logs to"),
        ),
    )

    parser, args = get_args(extra_args=extra_args, prog="My script")
    print(args)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```